# Does Stack Exchange have a similar topic for debian linux?

Tags: discussion

I know that this is Ubuntu but it is debian based and I'm not really using Ubuntu. Where can I go for general debian questions? Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

Questions about other linux systems go to https://unix.stackexchange.com/

[Please see the help on on-topic questions](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic):

> **Questions that you should avoid:**
>
> Linux Mint, Elementary OS, Backtrack, Gnome-Remix (prior to 13.04) and
>   other Linux distributions (try our friends at [Unix & Linux Stack
>   Exchange](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic)).

Comment: Why is there specifically an Ubuntu stackexchange though, and not a debian?

Comment: Because Canonical pays for it so it can be used as their support site. AU is the official Ubuntu support site. 2ndly: we (Ubuntu users) would SWARM U&L  and Debian is a relatively small subset on U&L.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from U&L, there is an ongoing proposal on Area51 for a separate Debian Stack Exchange. It is still in the definition stage, so go on and show your support: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/62467/debian

Comment: That proposal would need the support of the powers that be from Debian core dev team.  I wouldn't head straight there.  If I wanted it to work, I would head to 
Debian mailing lists and try to convince the core team of benefits a SE site could provide.  It would go MILES further than signing up for a beta and hashing out sample questions.

Comment: @hbdgaf thanks for the tip. But I've lost faith in Area 51 after the Vim debacle. I just put the link there since OP might be interested.

Comment: I've participated in 3 or 4 betas I think.  My goal isn't to be a solid community member in every beta to which I commit.  My goal is to provide a few solid answers and a few solid questions.  This way, people can see "I wouldn't have found that anywhere else"

Comment: I don't think they are going to get very far with that after reading some of the comments there.